# Symfony 2 on virtual hosts

Tags: symfony, virtualhost, host

I have a problem here with Symfony 2. I want to have virtual host on Windows Vista PC, so I can access my Symfony application like this `myapp.local.com`. 
What I have tried:

- I added these lines to hosts file

  ```
  127.0.0.1 local.com    
  127.0.0.1 myapp.local.com
  ```
- These I added to apache httpd-vhosts.conf

  ```
  < VirtualHost myapp.local.com:80 >
     DocumentRoot "d:/data/www/myapp/web"
     ServerName myapp.local.com
     Alias /sf /$sf_symfony_data_dir/web/sf
  < Directory "/$sf_symfony_data_dir/web/sf" >
     AllowOverride All
     Allow from All
  < /Directory >
  < Directory "d:/data/www/myapp/web" >
     AllowOverride All
     Allow from All
  < /Directory >
  < /VirtualHost >
  ```

but when I write `myapp.local.com` in my browser, it brings the index of my `www` directory. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are using the virtualhost configuration proposed for Symfony 1.

My virtualhost for Symfony2 under linux looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com.localhost
    ServerAlias domain.com.localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/user/www/project/web
    <Directory /home/user/www/project/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Try this (adapted to your config in windows), restart Apache, and try accessing the URL again.

You will find more informations on Symfony2 virtual hosts on [this cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html).

Comment: Ok, forgot the '/' in `Directory /home/user/www/project/web/>` line. Now I get the index of `web/` folder. Need to change something to refer to app.php I guess.

Comment: You need to install the mod_rewrite apache module

Comment: Or add line DirectoryIndex app.php

Comment: Thank you @Nanocom, that module was really missing :)

Comment: Symfony 1.x explicitly laid out vhost config in every demo/tutorial....why the hell is there a universal absence of all things vhost related in symfony2 documentation?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @herringtown [and what about this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html) The preferred (and easiest) way to start using Symfony2 is to use the php's built in web server and the `php ./app/console server:run` command. If you want to use a web server you probably know how to configure it and if not you should consult the web server's documentation.

Comment: Don't forget to go to the app_dev.php

Comment: Works with Symfony 4, just change `app.php` by `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Windows version for symfony 3.4:
Just simple like this:

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony_CRUD/web"
  DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
  ServerName fudu.symfony.net
</VirtualHost>
```

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1 fudu.symfony.net
```

Then you go `fudu.symfony.net/app_dev.php`
Hope it help some one :)