# Symfony2 config app base url

Tags: symfony, config, base-url

How can i get this base url

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/
```

OR

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app.php/
```

or

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/
```

(base url)

in symfony2 config file? can't find at symfony website.

Comment: Do you mean about url to put in your web browser to achieve project site? Check configuration of virtualHost.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';

$hostName = $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST');
$baseDirectory = "";
if(!empty($this->container->get('router')->getContext()->getBaseUrl())){
    $baseDirectory = str_replace('app_dev.php', '', $this->container->get('router')->getContext()->getBaseUrl());
}
$rootUrl = $protocol.$hostName.$baseDirectory;
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... check this:

```
$base = $this->getRequest()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

or in oldest version (I don't remember when was the change):

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$scheme = $request->getScheme();
$host = $request->getHttpHost();

$base = sprintf('%s://%s', $scheme, $host);
```

Comment: in symfony2 config file?
in symfony2 config file?
in symfony2 config file?

Comment: set manually in in `parameters.yml` and than use this in `config.yml` by name: `%your_name%`, in controller use my example. BTW: why in config? what for?

Comment: for JS bundle i need to set url
request_context_base_url: "http://localhost/name/web/app_dev.php"

Comment: FOSJsRequestBundle? maybe: `request_context_base_url:  ~` and `routes_to_expose` in `[]`.

Comment: i have everything ready just need this config url parameter... but FOSJS is giving me url like this http://localhost/messages/ and i need localhost/name/web/messages ... and i want it dynamicly not setted by me in parameters or somewhere else

Comment: @Trki server (f.e. apache) must be configured ( f.e. vhost ) on `web` directory and than `localhost/messages` will be correctly.

Comment: hm... i tried few times configure it but it was never working. Do you have some great tutorial or code in .txt in shortcut? :P

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony.localhost
    DocumentRoot /[path_to_symfony]/web
    <Directory /[path_to_symfony]/web>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: hm... and add it to...? :)

Comment: apache configuration, this is content of virtual host configuration file, look: [apache configuration for symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962054/symfony-2-on-virtual-hosts).