# symfony 'web folder' 404 error

Tags: symfony, xampp, http-status-code-404

I have recently installed symfony2, which I extracted into a local directory on my windows 7 machine, which is running the code through xampp.

My problem is that the "web" directory doesn't appear on the list of subdirectories when I navigate to localhost/symfony in a browser, and if I try to navigate direct to localhost/symfony/web, I get the "404" message.

And yet there it is sitting in my xammp file system in Windows, just like any other directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: figured it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351167/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You should use a virtual host who point directly to the web folder.

[Symfony 2 on virtual hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962054/symfony-2-on-virtual-hosts)