# Symfony use wrong domain to generate absolute URL

Tags: rest, symfony, hateoas

I'm currently building a Hal Hateoas RESTful API with [BazingaHateoasBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaHateoasBundle) and Symfony 2.7

Here is my config file :

```
MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity:
  relations:
    - rel: self
      href:
        route: get_myentity
        parameters:
          id: expr(object.getId())
        absolute: true
```

In local, I have an apache with a virtual host and my responses are correct :

```
{
    "id":1,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://dev.myvhost/api/myentity/1"
        }
}
```

In my dev server, I have something like this:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://my-machine-name/api/myentity/1"
        }
}
```

I don't want `my-machine-name` but `my-server-name.com` instead.

And my server Apache config look like this :

```
ServerName my-server-name.com
Alias "/api" "/var/www/api/web"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/api/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           Options -MultiViews
           RewriteEngine On
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/api/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/api_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/api_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to configure Symfony so that I can set directly the host maybe ?

Answer (score -2):

I think you're missing a step here. That is you need to add the my-server-name.com to the hosts file (of the system).

Here's another helpful link on the topic: [Symfony 2 on virtual hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962054/symfony-2-on-virtual-hosts)